# Relative paths in doxygen to allow continous integration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, continuous-integration, jenkins, doxygen

The aim is to create the documentation for my whole Visual Studio C# solution automatically with Doxygen. This should happen on an external buildserver with Jenkins. 
The structure of my project is like that:

```
Root
    Tools
        doxygen-1.8.0
            doxygen.exe
    Project1
        bin
        ...
    Project2
        bin
        ...
    ...
```

When creating a Doxyfile with the Doxywizard, the paths for the input and output are unfortunately absolute - which means that they depend on my developer machine and won't work on the Jenkins server anymore. Do you know how I can fix that? I have the suspicion that this has something to do with Doxygen's `FULL_PATH_NAMES`and `STRIP_FROM_PATH`, but to be honest, I don't get the descriptions of those two parameters. Maybe I am wrong and this hasn't anything to do with the 2 parameters at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether doxygen on Windows expects the configuration file to use Windows paths (with the backslash separator) or Unix paths (with the forward slash). Regardless, you should make sure your paths are relative to the directory from which you run doxygen.

In your Doxyfile, set the `INPUT` list and  `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to relative paths. Assuming you're running from within *Root*:

```
INPUT = ./Project1 \
        ./Project2
```

In general, you should update all the variables that specify paths to be relative (and make sure your resources are checked into source control).

In some of our projects, I've found it convenient to set the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY via an environment variable:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = $(DOXYGEN_OUTOUT_DIR)
```

in others, its just a relative path:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ./gen/docs
```

The leading `./` is not strictly necessary, but it's a readable indicator that this is a relative path.

The `FULL_PATH_NAMES` variable will not help you, it controls how the files appear in the generated File List.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will try that. But I forgot something: In the Wizard, you have to set the "Working directory from which Doxygen will run". What can I do here? (Apart from the fact I don't get why that is important. Shouldn't doxygen.exe know itself where it is located?)

Comment: The Doxyfile is just a text file. You may need to edit it directly. In the wizard, set the working directory to wherever you will run doxygen, which may not be the same as the directory where it's installed. Then edit the doxyfile to change absolute paths to relative paths.